# Integrations of Ricci curvature of the Weil-Petersson metric on the moduli space of varieties of general type is a rational numbers?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, moduli-spaces

It is known that the integrations of Ricci curvature of the Weil-Petersson metric on the moduli space of Calabi-Yau varieties is a rational numbers

> My question is about the moduli space of varieties of general type (varieties
>   with negative first Chern class) we have again Weil Petersson metric
>   and so the integrations of Ricci curvature of the Weil-Petersson
>   metric on the moduli space of varieties of general type is a rational
>   numbers?
>
> $$\int_M\omega_{WP}^m\in \mathbb Q$$